# How to write a function similar to $_GET?

Tags: php, function, get

Is there a function that works like $_GET ?
I mean a function that transforms

```
"?var1=5&var2=true"
```

to

```
$var1=5; 
$var2="true";
```

So that I can use one variable (string) in a function and fetch many variables from it?

Like:

```
function manual_GET($args){ /* ? */}

function myFunction($args)
{
manual_GET($args);
 if(isset($var1))/* doesn't have to be this way, btw */
 {
   do_something($var1);
 }
 //etc
}
```

p.s. : I don't want to use $_GET with URL because this file is a class file (namely database_library.php) so I don't execute it directly, or make an AJAX call. I just `require_once();` it.

Comment: [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) will, but the real question is _why_ would you do something like this?

Comment: @Jon Thanks, I was just explaining it with an edit.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. It is called `parse_str`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix it.

```
function myFunction($args){
 return parse_str($args,$values);
}
```

Comment: Umm.  What?  Where is `$value` assigned?  And how are you assuming the index `0` will be what is wanted?  And why on earth would you echo it instead of returning it.  Also... there are __no__ return values for the function. ^^  If you're going to demonstrate it, you should do so properly. ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseQueryString($str) { 
  $op = array(); 
  $pairs = explode("&", $str); 
  foreach ($pairs as $pair) { 
    list($k, $v) = array_map("urldecode", explode("=", $pair)); 
    $op[$k] = $v; 
  } 
 return $op;
```

}

it works like `parse_str` but doesn't convert spaces and dots to underscores

Answer (score 0):

> "?var1=5&var2=true"

```
foreach ($_GET AS $k=>$v){
     $$k=$v;
}

echo $var1; // print 5
echo $var2; // print true
```